# How to use vim to check the -h param or manual of some excutable file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim, vi

I want to use vim to check the -h param of pm2(a nodejs app),

and i want to use vim to check manual page,

```
man ascii | vim
```

```
pm2 -h | vim
```

dont not work, how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by _checking the `-h` param of `pm2`_?

Comment: Sure you don't want `less`, `more`, or another pager?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a way to read man pages in vim without using temporary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740246/what-is-a-way-to-read-man-pages-in-vim-without-using-temporary-files). After thinking better about it, I've marked the question as duplicate of the one I linked in my answer. I cannot see how the two subquestions here differ.

Comment: `:h Man` describes the built-in way for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to read the `man` page from `vim`, this is a way to accomplish the

```
man ascii | vim -
```

this is another:

```
vim <(man ascii)
```

The reason why `man ascii | vim` does not work, is because [`vim` does not take input from standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740302/5825294), unless you use `vim -`.

As suggested in a comment, are you sure `man ascii | less` is not enough for you? It allows you to search and move in the man page as `vim` would do (<kbd>/</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,...).

As regards checking the `-h` param of `pm2`, I have no clue what you mean. If by any chance you refer to `vim` being "aware" that `pm2` was called with that option, it does just make no sense.

Comment: This is wrong. `man` is not a pager, but it uses one. It will use `less` by default or whatever the `PAGER` environment variable contains.

Comment: @jordanm, `man man` reads `man  is the system's manual pager`. Maybe I miss some bit?

Comment: Also, if you want to just stream the output to stdout, you can set `PAGER=cat`

Comment: I've removed that bit, which I've mistakenly confirmed before being sure it was right (there was a missing full stop, which I rarely miss).

Comment: Interesting `man man`, refers to itself as a pager and less as an "output pager". I guess these are just semantics

Comment: However I've removed that bit because it is wrong that you cannot pipe _from_ man. It's `vim` which does not take input from stdin, so you cannot pipe _into_ it (unless you use `vim -`).

Comment: @jordanm, was that _less_ part of a joke?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis This is why you don't use lame puns to name your program :)